# Are group presentations useful in studying the pure math of a group as a whole?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, soft-question, group-presentation

Group presentations are often used by computers to quickly identify an element of a group or multiply two elements. However, they don't give a full understanding of the mathematical properties of a group. Can group presentations be used to find some of the mathematical properties of a group, or are group presentations only useful when trying to get an understanding of the elements and their orders rather than the mathematical properties of the group as a whole (for example, its representations or automorphism group)?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  Certainly, *all* the information about a group is present in a presentation of it, though it might be extremely difficult or impossible to extract it (most general questions of this form are undecidable).  Beyond that, well it's all a matter of context.  What information you are given and what you hope to discover.

Comment: I'm asking whether some interesting mathematical properties are readily accessible from a presentation.

Comment: Of course.  You can read off quotients.  In particular, it's usually easy to understand the abelianization.

Comment: How can you be sure that you selected a normal subgroup when you are "reading off a quotient?"

Comment: One obtains a quotient by adding relations.  To get the abelianization, for instance, just require that the generators commute.

Comment: These properties are obvious from the presentation, but what about other properties?

Comment: Your question is very vague.  The Word Problem is a formidable barrier...that pretty much means that no general question is decidable (I mean, if you can't tell if a group is trivial or not, what can you hope for?).  Of course, context is everything.

Comment: I mean, you can know the maximum order of an element, but how would it help with things like representations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say we want to know the automorphisms of the dihedral group of order
$2n$. We want do this using the presentation $G = \langle r,s | r^n = 1,s^2 = 1, sr = r^{-1}s\rangle$, where $n \geq 3$. Note that first some kind of construction is needed to be sure there really *is* such a group of order $2n$: from the presentation it's easy to see that group has order at most $2n$, but how do you know the actual order isn't smaller and maybe some hidden aspect makes it all collapse down to the trivial group?  I will ignore this issue and just take for granted we know the group has order $2n$.

If $f \colon G \to G$ is an automorphism then $f$ is determined by $f(r)$ and $f(s)$. Since
$$
G = \{1,r,\ldots,r^{n-1},s,rs,\ldots,r^{n-1}s\rangle
$$
and the last $n$ elements $s,rs,\ldots,r^{n-1}s$ have order $2$, $f(r)$ must be a power of $r$. Its order is $n$, so $f(r) = r^a$ where $a \in (\mathbf  Z/(n))^\times$. Then $f(s) = r^bs$ where $b \in \mathbf Z/(n)$.

Conversely, suppose $a \in (\mathbf Z/(n))^\times$ and $b \in \mathbf Z/(n)$.  We want to define an automorphism $f_{a,b} \colon G \to G$ where $f_{a,b}(r) = r^a$ and $f_{a,b}(s) = r^bs$. First we'll show there is a homomorphism $G \to G$ with those values at $r$ and $s$, and then we'll show it is an automorphism.

There is a unique homomorphism $F_2 = \langle x,y\rangle \to G$ where $x \mapsto r^a$ and $y \mapsto r^bs$. Let $K$ be its kernel. We have $x^n \mapsto (r^b)^n = (r^n)^b = 1$ and $y^2 \mapsto (r^bs)^2 = 2$, so $x^n$ and $y^2$ are in $K$. Also $yx \mapsto r^bsr^a = r^{b-a}s$ and $x^{-1}y \mapsto r^{-a}r^bs = r^{b-a}s$. Since $yx$ and $x^{-1}y$ are mapped to the same value, $(yx)(x^{-1}y)^{-1} \in K$. Since $K$ is normal, $K$ contains the normal subgroup $N$ that is generated by $x^n$, $y^2$, and $(yx)(x^{-1}y)^{-1}$, so the homomorphism $F_2 \to G$ induces a homomorphism $F_2/N \to G$. From the presentation of $G$, we have $F_2/N \cong G$ by $\overline{x} \mapsto r$ and $\overline{y} \mapsto s$. Thus we have a homomorphism $f \colon G \to G$ where $r \mapsto r^a$ and $s \mapsto r^bs$.
This has to be $f_{a,b}$ (it has the right values on the generating elements $r$ and $s$ of $G$, so we have proved $f_{a,b} \colon G \to G$ exists as a homomorphism.

Why is $f_{a,b}$ an automorphism? Since $G$ is finite, it suffices to prove $f_{a,b}$ is either injective or surjective. We'll show its surjective.
The image $f_{a,b}(G)$ is a subgroup of $G$ that contains $\langle f(r)\rangle = \langle r^j\rangle = \langle r\rangle$ and $r^is$, so $f_{a,b}(G)$ contains $r$ and $s = r^{-i}(r^is)$. Thus $f_{a,b}(G) = G$.

We have proved ${\rm Aut}(G) = \{f_{a,b} : a \in (\mathbf Z/(n))^\times, b \in \mathbf Z/(n)\}$. Check $f_{a,b} \circ f_{a',b'} = f_{aa',b + ab'}$. That is exactly how the matrices $(\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\0&1\end{smallmatrix})$ multiply when $a \in (\mathbf Z/(n))^\times$ and $b \in \mathbf Z/(n)$.
Each $f_{a,b}$ determines $a$ and $b$ since $r$ has order $n$ in $G$ (so $r^a$ determines $a \bmod n$ and $r^bs$ determines $b$ mod $n$).
Thus
$$
{\rm Aut}(G) \cong \left\{\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&1\end{pmatrix} : a \in (\mathbf Z/(n))^\times, b \in \mathbf Z/(n)\right\}.
$$

Comment: You asked the question less than an hour ago, so it's not advisable to accept an answer so soon. Give time for other people perhaps to provide an answer to compare with this one.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of a situation where you need a presentation of a group.

Suppose that we are given a group $G$, perhaps as a subgroup of $S_n$ for some $n$, and we also have a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$. A common question then is "does $N$ have a complement in $G$"?

We could solve this in a naive way by brute force by finding all subgroups of $G$ and then checking whether any of them are complements of $N$.

A more efficient way is to use a cohomological condition. There is a complement of $N$ in $G$ if and only if the identity map on $N$ extends to a derivation (crossed homomorphism) $G \to N$, and in that case the kernel of the derivation is a complement.

That condition can be checked moderately easily if we know a presentation of $G/N$, and if we do not know one already, then it is a good idea to compute one.

Incidentally, if we did want to find all of the subgroups of $G$, then presentations play a role in algorithms to do that.

A more general application is that a presentation of $G$  is useful/necessary for finding homomorphisms (or, in the example above, crossed homomorphisms) of $G$ to another group, and computing ${\rm Aut}(G)$ is a special case of that.